# Stored procedure syntax error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am searching the error for two hours, yet I can't find so far:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_diffmod`
     (IN para_diffmod LONGTEXT, 
      IN para_link LONGTEXT)
BEGIN

IF EXIT (
    SELECT website_link FROM diffmod WHERE website_link=para_link
    )THEN 
    DELETE FROM diffmod WHERE website_link=para_link;

ELSE
    INSERT INTO diffmod(website_id,website_link)
    SELECT id,link
    FROM   site_html
    Where  link=para_link;

    UPDATE diffmod
    SET diffmod_content= para_diffmod
    where website_link = para_link;

END IF; 
END
```

The above stored procedure works as if the link found, it will delete the row! If not, it will add and update the new link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change If EXIT to IF EXISTS

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_diffmod`( 
IN para_diffmod LONGTEXT, 
IN para_link LONGTEXT)
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT website_link FROM diffmod WHERE website_link=para_link
    )THEN 
    DELETE FROM diffmod WHERE website_link=para_link;

ELSE
    INSERT INTO diffmod(website_id,website_link)
    SELECT id,link
    FROM   site_html
    Where  link=para_link;

    UPDATE diffmod
    SET diffmod_content= para_diffmod
    where website_link = para_link;

END IF; 
END
```

Comment: can i know what did i miss out?

Comment: "If exists" clause is used for checking if query is returning any rows. You had "If exit" in place of "if exists"

Comment: Oh man ! missing 's' and looking for 2 hour . Thanks a lot. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Achilles please mark my answer as correct if you feel it solved your problem